# Is $((\frac{1}{a})^{\frac{1}{b}})^{\frac{1}{c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[bc]{a}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Is $((\frac{1}{a})^{\frac{1}{b}})^{\frac{1}{c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[bc]{a}}$?

I believe it is since $((\frac{1}{a})^{\frac{1}{b}})^{\frac{1}{c}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[b]{a}}^\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[bc]{a}}$.

Can someone please confirm my suspicions as I just came across a question that states in the answer that $((\frac{1}{a})^{\frac{1}{b}})^{\frac{1}{c}}=\sqrt[bc]{a}$ and I believe that this is a typo.

Comment: Yeah... its a typo.  Let $M = \frac 1a$ then $((M)^{\frac 1b})^{\frac 1c} = (\sqrt[b]M)^{\frac 1c} = \sqrt[c]{\sqrt[b]M}= \sqrt[bc]{M}= M^{\frac 1{bc}}$ and $M$ or $\frac 1a$ or $\frac {57\pi}{\sqrt[3]{e- 19}}$ or whatever you stick into the center will be the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a, b, c > 0$, yes, you are correct.  This is easy to check:  choose $a = 729 = 3^6$, $b = 1/2$, $c = 1/3$.  We must obviously have $((1/a)^{1/b})^{1/c} < 1$, but $\sqrt[6]{729} > 1$.

Comment: We can weaken the constraints to $a>0,\,bc\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

${ \left( {\frac{1}{a}}^{\frac{1}{b}} \right)}^{\frac{1}{c}}= { \frac{1}{a}}^{ \frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{c}} =   { \frac{1}{a} }^{ \frac{1}{bc}} = \frac{1}{a^{\frac{1}{bc}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[bc]{a}}$

Thus, yes (assuming $a,b,c$ are all positive reals).

Comment: Oh, I have no idea where I messed up a paranthesis :(

Comment: Finally, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

*assuming* you are working with positive real numbers and *assuming* you are using the definition that if $m \ne 1$ and $m > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb N$ the $m^{\frac 1k}$ is defined to be (and you have proven there *is* such) the unique one and only positive number $w$ so that $w^k = m$ then

$((\frac 1a)^{\frac 1b})^{\frac 1c}$ (assuming $a\ne 1$) is the unique

$\beta$ so that $\beta^c = (\frac 1a)^{\frac 1b}$.

And $(\frac 1a)^{\frac 1b}$ is the unique $\gamma$ so that $\gamma^b = \frac 1a$.

But then $\beta^{bc} = (\beta^c)^b = ((\frac 1a)^{\frac 1b})^b = \gamma^b = \frac 1a$.

So $beta$ is the unique value so that $\beta^{bc} = \frac 1a$ so $\beta = (\frac 1a)^{\frac 1{bc}$.

SO $((\frac 1a)^{\frac 1b})^{\frac 1c}=\beta = (\frac 1a)^{\frac 1{bc}}$